# Displaying a combobox for a OneToOneField

Tags: django, html, combobox

I would like to show a combobox with a `OneToOneField`:

**models.py:**

```
class Aliment(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    type_aliment_id = models.OneToOneField(type_aliment)
    mesurande_id = models.OneToOneField(mesurande)
    calories = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    proteines = models.IntegerField(default=0)

class type_aliment(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

**forms.py:**

```
class AlimentForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=Aliment
        field = ('name','type_aliment_id','mesurande_id','calories','proteines')
```

**views.py:**

```
def add_aliment(request):
  add_aliment = AlimentForm()
  return render_to_response("add_aliment.html",
                          {'form_aliment':add_aliment,},RequestContext(request))
```

And I Would like to show all columns of "Aliment" but for "type_aliment_id" i would like to have a combobox with all names in "type_aliment" :
And it doesn't work but i don't know why :

```
<form id="myForm" action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
  <select name="select_type" id="id_select_type">
    {% for type_aliment in form_aliment.type_aliment_id %}
    <option value="{{ type_aliment.id }}">{{ type_aliment.name}}</option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to construct your combobox manually. It will automatically be created by Django. Just use

```
<form id="myForm" action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form_aliment }}
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</select>
```

as the basis for your template.

You also have to implement the `__unicode__` method in your class to see their names in the combo box:

```
class type_aliment(models.Model):
    ...
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

**PS**: Your naming convention is confusing. Try to stick with Python/Django standards. Use CamelCase for class names; for example, instead of

```
class type_aliment(...)
```

use

```
class TypeAliment(...)
```

and don't add the `_id` suffix to your field names. Instead of

```
type_aliment_id = models.OneToOneField(type_aliment)
```

use

```
type_aliment = models.OneToOneField(TypeAliment)
```

it will help fellow coders (like here on Stack Overflow) read your code more easily.

Comment: no because with your solution, in the combobox for type_aliment, we don't see the attributs of type_aliment but the types for all objects (<object type type_aliment>) instead of the values of attributs (vegetables for example) do you understand ?

Comment: To see the `name` attribute in the combobox you have to override the `unicode` method. See my updated answer.

Comment: ok thank's a lot it works for me with "__unicode__" not "unicode"

Comment: @clementl Gosh, you are right. I corrected it in my answer.